# Refresh NextJS query parameters on SSR React app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have Server Side Render set up, so every time an user visit a page, for example
`mypage?query=one`
nextjs will cache that value for **all** the user, which is of course wrong.

So even if the user will have
`mypage?query=two`
still nextjs `router.query` function will return the value **one** while `asPath` is correct (showing the current URL).

How can I, in a class component, update the cached version with the **current** query? Which lifecycle is more opportune to use?

Comment: if you need a specific value for each user, you need some kind of "storage" for each user. E.g. you can use a database on the server (with one data set per user), or you use cookies or the `localStorage` of the users browser.